# Help With Partial Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
A=(A_0/z)\exp[-jk(x^{2}+y^{2})/2z]
$$
$$
\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{x}} = -jxA\frac{k}{z} 
$$
Can anybody explain why this is the case? I thought that exponential functions never disappeared when one does derivatives.

Comment: It didn't disappear it is still in the $A$ at the right!

Comment: Do not loose track that it is an implicit derivative. The derived function actually appears in its derived expression.

Comment: I see now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't disappear. What you didn't write is, that A is a function depending on $x$. Actually you have

$\partial_x A = -jk\frac{k}{z}A(x)$

and the $\exp$ is included in your function A(x). This is the prototype of an ordinary differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=e^x$. Then $B'=B$. Has the exponential dísappeared?